# Swift can't return subclass as superclass

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have this base class:

```
class FieldModel<T>{
   var pageModel : PageModel
   var fieldId : String
   var fieldTitle : String
   var required : Bool

   var type : String
   var rule : ShowHideRule?
   var fieldValue : T?


   init(json:JSON, pageModel : PageModel){
       //not important
   }
}
```

and this subclass:

```
class HeaderFieldModel : FieldModel<String> {    
   override init(json: JSON, pageModel: PageModel) {
       super.init(json: json, pageModel: pageModel)
   }
}
```

Why does

```
class FieldFactory {
    class func createField< T : FieldModel<AnyObject> >
        (json: JSON, pagemodel: PageModel) -> T {

            let type = json["type"].stringValue

            switch type {
            case "header":
                return HeaderFieldModel(json: json, pageModel: pagemodel)
            case "mood":
                return MoodFieldModel(json: json, pageModel: pagemodel)
            // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... give me:

> Cannot convert return expression of type `HeaderFieldModel` to return type `T`

The class I'm returning fulfills the condition, it's subclassing FieldModel.
Even if I change the generic type from AnyObject to String, to make it exactly the same as in HeaderFieldModel, nothing changes.

Comment: `FieldModel<String>` is not a subclass of `FieldModel<AnyObject>`.  It's not even a subclass of `FieldModel<Any>`.   Generic of a subclass is not a subclass of a generic of a superclass :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generic constrain says:

```
T : FieldModel<AnyObject>
```

T is defined as a subclass of `FieldModel`. One specific subclass is supposed to be returned from this method.

However, your `switch` is returning two or more different subclasses, not one single subclass.

What you actually want is:

```
class func createField(json: JSON, pagemodel: PageModel) -> FieldModel<String>
```

You want the method to be able to return any subclass of `FieldModel`, not one specific subclass.

Of course, also note that `HeaderFieldModel` is not a subclass of `FieldModel<AnyObject>`.

Comment: If I have many subclasses, with different type (es. FieldModel<String> and FieldModel<Int>), how can I make it so the function is able to return all of them in the switch? I thought using AnyObject would solve this issue.

And, following the same logic, I would not be able to put all these different instances of FieldModel<T> into a single array, would I?

Comment: @Jack First you need to give them a common interface, e.g. using a protocol. Then you can return that type that represents the interface. Maybe you don't actually want to use generics, maybe you want to use protocols with associated types or enums for associated types.

Comment: That was actually the first way I went for, but it is not possible to use a protocol with an associated type as a general type. And I need the associated type or something that can replace it.